# Laravel - ACL - Different roles for different schools

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-backpack

I'm fairly new to Laravel and been looking all over for this answer but not able to find anything that fits my requirements.

Basically I want the ability for a single login user to be assigned multiple roles based a specific school.

So for example:

School A: The User is student School B: The User is Manager School C: The User is a manager and Teacher

Ideally in the UI, a user can login and then switch between the schools he is registered to. Then depending on what school he chooses he will possibly be a different role (Teacher, Student, Manager).

I have also been looking at morphing but not sure if that's the right solution because of the fact that I want the ability for a user to possibly have multiple roles assigned to a particular school.

Comment: Use this one https://github.com/Hesto/multi-auth

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this as follow:

- Keep a record of the user with their role for respective schools
- On Login => Select a default school, store it in session and assign the respective role
- Allow drop-down selector to change school
- On Change update session value and role

For role and permission, you can use this: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission